# Printer driver not working in 22.04 lts

Tags: usb, printing, laptop, canon, 22.04

Successfully installed CANON CAPT Drivers on the updated Ubuntu LTS. Printer not printing even after giving print command several times. Even "Print Test Page" failed. Please help.

Comment: Look at the CUPS interface by browsing to `http://localhost:631`. Click on the Administration tab and add your printer there.

Comment: This script works for me on Lubuntu 22.04 with a CANON LBP6000B https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer

Answer (score 3):

If your pc username and password do not work try the following

add your username to lpadmin group

```
sudo usermod -aG lpadmin username
```

Then restart CUPs

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it worked for me. It's strange how Ubuntu 22.04 got this bug. Please consider formatting username as a template: <username>